# Mutating vs Copying yielding different float values

Tags: c++

For context, I'm fairly new to C++. I have these set of functions:

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} vec3_t;

vec3_t vec3_rotate_x(const vec3_t& v, double angle) {
    vec3_t rotated_vector = {
        .x = v.x,
        .y = v.y * cos(angle) - v.z * sin(angle),
        .z = v.y * sin(angle) + v.z * cos(angle)
    };

    return rotated_vector;
}

vec3_t vec3_rotate_y(const vec3_t& v, double angle) { 
    vec3_t rotated_vector = { 
        .x = v.x * cos(angle) - v.z * sin(angle), 
        .y = v.y, 
        .z = v.x * sin(angle) + v.z * cos(angle) 
    };

    return rotated_vector;
}

vec3_t vec3_rotate_z(const vec3_t& v, double angle) { 
    vec3_t rotated_vector = { 
        .x = v.x * cos(angle) - v.y * sin(angle), 
        .y = v.x * sin(angle) + v.y * cos(angle), 
        .z = v.z 
    };

    return rotated_vector;
}
```

And here's how it's being used:

```
for (vec3_t transformed_vertex : face_vertices) {
    transformed_vertex = vec3_rotate_x(transformed_vertex, mesh.rotation.x);
    transformed_vertex = vec3_rotate_y(transformed_vertex, mesh.rotation.y);
    transformed_vertex = vec3_rotate_z(transformed_vertex, mesh.rotation.z);
    ...
```

I'm basically passing the struct in, making a copy via "rotated_vector" with some modified values, and returning it. That begs the question, why create a "rotated_vector" in the first place if I'm just going to assign the return value back to "transformed_vertex"

Okay, so I "optimize" it to:

```
void vec3_rotate_x(vec3_t& v, double angle) {
    v.y = v.y * cos(angle) - v.z * sin(angle);
    v.z = v.y * sin(angle) + v.z * cos(angle);
}

void vec3_rotate_y(vec3_t& v, double angle) { 
    v.x = v.x * cos(angle) - v.z * sin(angle); 
    v.z = v.x * sin(angle) + v.z * cos(angle); 
}

void vec3_rotate_z(vec3_t& v, double angle) { 
    v.x = v.x * cos(angle) - v.y * sin(angle); 
    v.y = v.x * sin(angle) + v.y * cos(angle); 
}
```

And the new code is:

```
for (vec3_t transformed_vertex : face_vertices) {
    vec3_rotate_x(transformed_vertex, mesh.rotation.x);
    vec3_rotate_y(transformed_vertex, mesh.rotation.y);
    vec3_rotate_z(transformed_vertex, mesh.rotation.z);
    ...
```

The operations are all the same, but I'm getting different values. Here are the outputs after a single loop:

```
// unoptimized code output
{ x=-0.97990184160224847 y=-0.99979901171636831 z=-1.0198991700141220 }

// "optimized" code output 
{ x=-0.97990284650179404 y=-0.99969953513531573 z=-1.0196971968296114 }
```

The difference is minuscule at first, but it builds up over many loops. I don't understand why I'm getting different outputs between my two sets of functions. I've checked and all the inputs are identical. Is there some float math difference that I'm not understanding between the two sets of functions?

Comment: You are modifying `v.x` in your reference functions, which means the `v.y` and `v.z` calculations are going to be different since `v.x` is now different.

Comment: Side note: `typedef struct { ... } vec3_t;` is a C-ism. C++ learned a lot from C, and baked this `typedef` trick directly into the language. All you need is `struct vec3_t { ... };`

Answer (score 0):

Someone else helped you find the math problem, but why not do this:

```
struct vec3 {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

    void vec3_rotate_x(double angle) {
        float oldY = y;
        y = y * cos(angle) - z * sin(angle);
        z = oldY * sin(angle) + z * cos(angle);
    }

    void vec3_rotate_y(double angle) { 
        float oldX = x;
        x = x * cos(angle) - z * sin(angle); 
        z = oldX * sin(angle) + z * cos(angle); 
    }

    void vec3_rotate_z(double angle) { 
        x = x * cos(angle) - y * sin(angle); 
        y = x * sin(angle) + y * cos(angle); 
    }
};
```

It's C++. Methods should be attached to the classes they manipulate.

Comment: _"Methods should be attached to the classes they manipulate." _ the amount of possible manipulations is infinite. When would you draw the line and start adding free functions with overloads? Absolutely no need for introducing mutable state

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik If you want to program in a functional fashion, you can do so and still use member functions. But why would you pick an OO language and ignore OO features? These are very well-known mathematical operations on vectors. You're going to have a vector class that doesn't understand its basic math operations? If so, great, but I wouldn't.

Comment: why do you decide to stop here? Make those fields private/protected, add  getters, setters, use RAII to maintain invariants - add constructors, virtual destructor. Add NVI methods, make it a base CRTP class... Why ignore all that features? Don't forget to make all the methods non-static and mutable, so it would be very hard to use const objects and impossible to use as constexpr...

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik This really isn't the place to debate the merits of functional vs. OO programming. Any tool can be abused, though. Including, apparently the comment section in StackOverflow.

Comment: _"...apparently the comment section in StackOverflow."_ I don't see how the comment section is abused more than the "answer" section